# Enum: type name is not allowed

Tags: c++

I am a .Net C# programmer trying to program in C++. I have an application that uses a third party library. When i try and use an Enum from the library in a function for this library I get an error message of type not allowed:

I have included the library:

```
#include <Trading.h>

using namespace Trading;
```

Trading.h includes Enumerations.h that contains:

```
/// Returns string representation.
FOO std::string enumToString (TimeInForce::Enum);

/// Trading session event type.
struct FOO TradSesEvent
{
    /// @copydoc TradSesEvent
    enum Enum
    {
       ...
    };
};
```

Code of the Application.cpp simplified to the problem:

```
#include <Trading.h>

using namespace Trading;

class Application
{
public:
    Application(const Settings& settings) : settings_(settings)
    {
        orderBook_.reset(new OrderBook());
    ...
    }

private:
    // Store of orders sent to counterparty.
    PtrTraits<OrderBook>::UniquePtr orderBook_;

    void onSendNewOrder(Order& newOrder)
    {
        //create unique_ptr to fill in the order values and sen

        PtrTraits<Order>::UniquePtr order(new Order(orderBook_->newId()));

        order->timeInForce = TimeInForce.Day;
        ...
    }
};
```

Error message:

> struct Application::TimeInForce type name is not allowedC/C++(254)

Comment: These disjointed code snippets are difficult to follow. Can you follow stackoverflow.com's instructions to create a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, and reproduce the exact compilation error you're asking about?

Comment: What does `FOO std::string enumToString` mean?

Comment: how can i create a minimum reproducible example with a 3rd party library?

Comment: @AmiTavory `FOO` is probably a `declspec` placeholder. It shouldn't be in a MCVE.

Comment: @azuric By abstracting it away. You didn't even show the definition of `TimeInForce`, which is rather important for an error message about `TimeInForce`. If abstracting away the third party library fixes the problem, then _the problem is in the third party library_, meaning (a) we couldn't help you anyway, and (b) you should talk to the developers of that library. That's debugging: narrowing down the problem. It's a step you must take first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for naming a member of an unscoped enum declared in a class or namespace `TimeInForce` is:

```
TimeInForce::Day
```

The period (`.`) is used for accessing *non-static* members of classes.